# 2023—Keynote 13.0—how to change background texture's color?

Tags: keynote, color, multitasking

I'm trying to change the color of the background linen texture on Keynote Master Slides from olive green to the dusty blue seen here: [image]

I was able to change the background color on the ***plain*** slides, as seen in that image, but am not able to change the edges on slides built of several layers (by Apple) to simulate a book page.

I have gone into **Applications>Keynote.app>Contents>Resources** to look at the assets and found some useful items *(i.e., canvas_bluepurple_low_res.jpg, canvas_bluepurple_mipmaps.plist, canvas_bluepurple_jpg, Linen.sfcimage.plist, Linen.sfctex.plist, tile_bluepurple.jpg)* but don't see how to use them to change the theme color for ALL the slide masters.

I know this has been asked before (https://bit.ly/3KqLVI2) but responders didn't seem to understand the OP's question. I hope the image I've shared above—showing the green tint to the linen frame around the slide (making it look like a linen-covered book) and the blue-purple color I was able to use as a background for the Title Slide—will help clarify.

Comment: Try inserting the image directly ***in*** the question, not as a link, it's always better for people to read.

Comment: Thank you, @Thinkr! Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: It does! Thanks!